# Merge SPSS variables if they don't exist in the original file, using Python

Tags: python, merge, spss

I have an SPSS file that I am removing unwanted variables from, but want to bring in variables from elsewhere if they don't exist. So, I am looking for some Python code to go into my syntax to say - keep all the variables from a list and if any of these don't exist in the first file, then merge them in from the second file. (Python rookie here..)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an apporach to get you started:

```
DATA LIST FREE / ID A B C D E.
BEGIN DATA
1 11 12 13 14 15
END DATA.
DATASET NAME DS1.

DATA LIST FREE /  ID D E F G H.
BEGIN DATA
1 24 25 26 27 28
END DATA.
DATASET NAME DS2.

BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spssaux, spss
spss.Submit("dataset activate ds1.")
ds1vars=[v.VariableName for v in spssaux.VariableDict()]
spss.Submit("dataset activate ds2.")
ds2vars=[v.VariableName for v in spssaux.VariableDict()]

extravars = [v for v in ds2vars if v not in ds1vars]

spss.Submit("""

DATASET ACTIVATE DS2.
ADD FILES FILE=* /KEEP=ID %s.
MATCH FILES FILE=DS1 /TABLE DS2 /BY ID.
DATASET NAME DS3.
DATASET ACTIVATE DS3.

""" % (" ".join(extravars) ) )

END PROGRAM PYTHON.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just `match files` regardless of what variables are missing, only the variables that exist in the `table` and do not exist in the `file` will be added to the `file`.
Note though you'll have trouble if you have text vars in both files with identical names but different widths.